# Is union of family of inner models also an inner model?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

For every ordinal $\alpha$ let $M_\alpha$ be an inner model of $\mathsf{ZF}$ so that for every set of ordinal $S$ there exists an ordinal $\beta$ such that $\bigcup_{\alpha \in S} M_\alpha \subset M_\beta$. Is $\bigcup_{\alpha} M_\alpha$ also an inner model of $\mathsf{ZF}$?

In Jech's *Set Theory* there is a criterion for inner model. It says that a transitive class $M$ is an inner model of $\mathsf{ZF}$ iff it is closed under Gödel operations and is almost universal, i.e., every subset $X \subset M$ is included in some $Y \in M$. $\bigcup_{\alpha} M_\alpha$ is obviously transitive and closed under Gödel operations. It is also almost universal since every $X \subset \bigcup_{\alpha} M_\alpha$ is contained in some $M_\alpha$. Thus $\bigcup_{\alpha} M_\alpha$ is an inner model of $\mathsf{ZF}$. Is this correct?

If this is correct, I think the class constructed in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/770130/318407) can be proven to be an inner model of $\mathsf{ZF}$ without extra works like tweaking it to make certain form of Reflection principle work for proving Separation.

Comment: I don't think this is true. I'm not really a set theorist (and I just barely have any idea about how iterated forcing works), so I might very well be missing something, but consider a sequence $M_\alpha$ where $M_\alpha$ is the forcing extension of $L$ by Cohen forcing iterated $\alpha$ times. Then $\bigcup_\alpha M_\alpha$ will not have the power set of $\omega$, since no set of subsets of $\omega$ in any $M_\alpha$ will have all the Cohen reals we add along the way.

Comment: The problem may not be if none of the subsets in $\omega$ will have all the Cohen reals added, but if none of the "internal powersets" $\{x\in M_\alpha\mid x\subseteq\omega\}$ will have all of them.